# Somebody's opus, if not mine

Tags: knowledge, rebus

My coworkers and and I were talking about a specific person the other day.  Who were we talking about?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You were talking about:

> **Satoshi Kon**, who directed: Perfect Blue (top left), Millennium Actress (bottom left - Catherine Black (played by Megan Gallagher) in X-Files, who is associated with the Millennium Group, and appeared in the X-Files series Millennium), Tokyo Godfathers (top right - a Japanese version of The Godfather), and Paprika (bottom right - from Blue's Clues)

Comment: Well done!  Were image searches involved, or did you know them?

Comment: I knew the top left :P (Being the culturally illiterate person I am, I image searched the rest, although yeah I can see the top right faintly. Then the association came from a reasonably good google search, with the bottom left misidentified)